# Replace < sign with &gt; and & with &amp; in XML file at particular node or position

Tags: javascript, html

> Hi All,
>
> I have a XML file which have a node called Section as below. As XML
>   treats & and < as an invalid characters. So i want to replace < sign
>   with < and & with & in Section Node only as shown below.

I am using below code in Javascript :-

```
if (xmlString.indexOf("&") >= 0 || xmlString.indexOf("<") >= 0)
{
    xmlString = xmlString.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
}
```

When i use above code, then it replaces all < brecket with < like every start tag. I want < should be there only in section node.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <webpage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Tabs>
      <Tab Name="Description">
         <Section Name="Description < &">
            <Field Type="Hidden" Property="EmployeeID" Desc="Employee ID" ColWidth="20"/>
         </Section>
     </Tab>
    </Tabs>
</Webpage>
```

XML file should be:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <webpage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Tabs>
      <Tab Name="Description">
         <Section Name="Description &lt; &amp;">
            <Field Type="Hidden" Property="EmployeeID" Desc="Employee ID" ColWidth="20"/>
         </Section>
     </Tab>
    </Tabs>
</Webpage>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: `I have a XML file which have a node called Section as below` - technically, you do not have a **valid** XML file if it isn't valid XML - perhaps you can fix the broken process that creates the broken XML file, rather than using regex on XML, which only leads to Zalgo

Comment: For security purpose, i did not provide whole XML. 
Do you have any solution on how to replace < on section node only?

Comment: I didn't ask you to show the whole XML file ... I asked why are you claiming it is an XML file, since it isn't valid XML? My proposal was that you **fix whatever is creating an invalid XML file in the first place** - this is by far the easiest solution

Comment: Since **'<'** sign does not work in XML. When i use **$.parseXML** method, then it shows invalid XML. That is the reason i need to replace **'<' sign** with **'&lt;'** to parse it a valid XML.

How to find out Section node or name and find less than sign inside it and replace only in Section node.

Comment: but, if you had "valid XML" in the first place, then you wouldn't need to worry about it - fixing it in the reader side is prone to many edge case errors, and the summoning of Zalgo

Comment: you need to search for `<Section.*>` however, what if there's a `>` in the attribute? so, you'll need to search for `<Section.*=".*">` and carefully "edit" the matched text ... but what if an attribute iss like `someattribute=">blah"` ? then ... see where I'm going with this? fix the XML writer

Comment: How do i search **<Section.*=".*">** using Javascript and how to find < bracket within Section and replace it.
Can you plz give me the code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you want regex on broken XML ... here we go

```js
var brokenXML = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webpage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Tabs>
    <Tab Name="Description">
      <Section Name="Description < &">
        <Field Type="Hidden" Property="EmployeeID" Desc="Employee ID" ColWidth="20" />
      </Section>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
</webpage>`;

// here's the magic replace - forgive me Zalgo
var fixedXML = brokenXML.replace(/(<)(Section .*=".*")(>)/g, (match, cap1, cap2, cap3) => `${cap1}${cap2.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('<', '&lt;')}${cap3}`);

// to show it works now

var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fixedXML, 'text/xml');
console.log(xml.firstChild.outerHTML);
```